# Sync files between 2 remote computers using Linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, sync, rsync

I want to be able to synchronise files between 2 remote computers in both directions. Say for example that I want to synchronise my `/home/Documents` directory with `<username>@example.com:/home/Documents`

What's the easiest way to update the folders in both directions, so that new/updated files on my home computer get transferred to the remote computer, and new/updated files on the remote computer get transferred to my home computer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). Here are some guides:

- [Using Unison to Synchronize Two Directories](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/unison.htm)
- [File Synchronization with Unison](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7712)
- [Synchronize computers with Unison](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/synchronize-computers-with-unison/115)
- [Synchronizing 2 Ubuntu Systems with Unison](http://www.micahcarrick.com/unison-synchronize-ubuntu.html)

Comment: I no longer use Linux on a day to day basis, but a few years ago when I did Unison was my choice for sync functionality of home dir.

Comment: @mindless.panda What are you using for syncing today?

Answer (score 2):

I use `rsync` (over ssh), just because it's easy and simple.

To sincronize two ways, you can do two commands, like this:

```
rsync --recursive --progress --partial --rsh=ssh /home/Documents <username>@example.com:/home/Documents
rsync --recursive --progress --partial --rsh=ssh <username>@example.com:/home/Documents /home/Documents
```

**EDIT:** I've just remembered somebody suggesting [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) at a sprint. As the home page states, `duplicity` is an "encrypted bandwidth-efficient backup using the rsync algorithm".